# Is there a reason for me to use Bintray if we are a node.js shop?

Tags: npm, package-managers, bintray

If I understand correctly, Bintray is a multi-faceted package management solution (e.g., it can manage not only npm packages, but also rubyGems and a lot of others) see [this diagram from jfrog](https://www.jfrog.com/bintray/); and I understand npm server provide the same capability, but only for node.js package formats, see [this blog from npmjs](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/75707294465/new-npm-registry-architecture)

My question is whether I my understanding toward Bintray is correct. i.e., if my goal is to build a private npm package manager service for my org, Bintray and npm server has no fundamental difference to achieve the goal from functionality perspective.

Answer (score 5):

I think the biggest reason to use Bintray, is its **Universal** solution.
I assume that on top of developing with **node.js**, you might also pack your apps as a **Docker** image, **Vagrant** box or an **RPM** package for distribution. Bintray will allow you to use it for Docker, Vagrant and RPM distributions too!
Of course, there are many other package types supported.

Look in https://www.jfrog.com/bintray/bintray-features/ for a long list of additional features that make Bintray a great solution for all your distribution needs.

I hope this helps.